# Yii 1, get SQL generated by CDbCriteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cactivedataprovider

got a problem, I need to get all ids of models (not only visible but all models) in CGridView. For that I use its DataProvider - get a criteria from it and pass it to command builder

```
$criteria = $dataProvider->getCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'id';
$command = Y::db()->commandBuilder->createFindCommand('tableName', $criteria);
$ids = $command->queryColumn();
```

It is working fine until we got filtering via related tables. For example user adds a number to a filter of the grid - "House Number" = 24. When it happens related table - "address" adds to `$criteria->with` and "address.home_number = 24" adds to `$criteria->condition`.

ActiveRecord automatically parses the "with" property of criteria and apply joins, so our condition would be fine with it, but CommandBuilder - not. I can't use AR for it, since it is deadly slow. I must use Builder, but I can't make joins, there could be more than 20 filters applied.

If I could get SQL generated by AR and then pass it to Builder - it would be great.

Answer (score -1):

After some research I've created custom class ActiveFinder - copy of CActiveFinder class of Yii framework. So you can just pass model you are gonna search and the criteria in new static method:

```
$model = new User();
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 't.id';
$command = ActiveFinder::getCommand($model, $criteria);
// $command variable have the SQL text
$sql = $command->text;
```

here you can grab the class - 
https://github.com/LinGG/ActiveFinder

Comment: Even this custom ActiveFinder isn't maybe the best way of doing this, it works. From my point of view it would be better if ActiveFinder extends CActiveFinder and add this static getCommand and overwrite other functions that should be changed...

Comment: I just created it for my needs in a short timeframe. If you want to make it better you are welcome :)

Comment: I understand that, and it is enough good to do the job. I just mention it because you had -1 for some reason. I wish to say that even it is not some great example how to do it, it still do the job.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. It is very easy to try it and it works :)